# Error when using msmFit in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to simulate this paper (*Point Forecast Markov Switching Model for U.S. Dollar/ Euro Exchange Rate*, by Hamidreza Mostafei) in R. The table that I'm trying to get is on page 483. [Here](http://www.ukm.my/jsm/pdf_files/SM-PDF-41-4-2012/14%20Hamidreza.pdf) is a link to a pdf.

I wrote the following codes and then got an error at the last line:

```
mydata <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\EURUSD_2.csv", header=T)   
mod    <- lm(EURUSD~EURUSD.1, mydata)  
mod.mswm = msmFit(mod, k=2, p=1, sw=c(T,T,T,T), control=list(parallel=F))

Error in if ((max(abs(object["Fit"]["logLikel"] - oldll))/(0.1 + max(abs(object["Fit"]["logLikel"]))) <  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Basically the data that's being used is `EURUSD`, which is the level change in monthly frequency. `EURUSD.1` is the one lag variable. Both `EURUSD` and `EURUSD.1` are in my csv file. (I'm not sure how to attach the csv file here. If someone could point that out that would be great).

I changed the `EURUSD.1` values to something random and `msmFit` function seemed to work. But whenever I tried using the original value, i.e. the lag value, the error came out.

Comment: Relatively poor question on software instead of on statistics. In the current form, is also not suited for SO (too little details and no reproducible example).

Comment: Thank you for adding more information to your question. Your Q should be able to be migrated to SO now. You cannot attach a csv file in SE. You can upload it to [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) & paste a link to it.

Comment: Noted. The link to the file is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/52tayiwnnmuxdoq/EURUSD_2.csv?dl=0

Comment: Where does `msmFit` come from? (maybe the MSwM package?)

Comment: Also, that PDF link doesn't work (looks like a nonexistent domain name error "Firefox can't find the server at www.ukm.my.")

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Any new insight about it?

Answer (score 0):

Something degenerate is happening when one variable is simply lagged from the other. Consider:

Sample data frame where Y is lagged X:

```
> d = data.frame(X=runif(100))
> d$Y=c(.5, d$X[-100])
> mod    <- lm(X~Y,d)  
> mod.mswm = msmFit(mod, k=2, p=1, sw=c(T,T,T,T), control=list(parallel=F))
Error in if ((max(abs(object["Fit"]["logLikel"] - oldll))/(0.1 + max(abs(object["Fit"]["logLikel"]))) <  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

that gives your error. Let's add a tiny tiny bit of noise to Y and see what happens:

```
> d$Y=d$Y+rnorm(100,0,.000001)
> mod    <- lm(X~Y,d)  
> mod.mswm = msmFit(mod, k=2, p=1, sw=c(T,T,T,T), control=list(parallel=F))

> mod.mswm
Markov Switching Model

Call: msmFit(object = mod, k = 2, sw = c(T, T, T, T), p = 1, control = list(parallel = F))

     AIC      BIC  logLik
  4.3109 47.45234 3.84455

Coefficients:
        (Intercept)(S)      Y(S)    X_1(S)     Std(S)
Model 1      0.8739622 -22948.89  22948.83 0.08194545
Model 2      0.4220748  77625.21 -77625.17 0.21780764

Transition probabilities:
          Regime 1  Regime 2
Regime 1 0.3707261 0.3886715
Regime 2 0.6292739 0.6113285
```

It works! Now either:

Having perfectly lagged variables causes some "divide by zero" error because its a purely degenerate case (like having perfectly co-linear variables in a linear model). A little experimenting shows that in this case the resulting output is **very** sensitive to how much noise you add, so I'm thinking its on a knife-edge here. I suspect having perfectly lagged variables here leads to some singularity or degeneracy.

or

There's some bug in the function.

I have no idea what `msmFit` does, so that's for you to sort out.