# Markov Switching-Autoregressive in R

Tags: r, markov-chains

I'm trying to replicate this paper but using different time period
https://www.dropbox.com/s/edwdpgwsbli93f1/SM35%282%29-09-modelling.pdf?dl=0.

This paper is about detecting regime shifts in Malaysian currency i.e the ringgit. From what I understand it uses Markov Switching-Autoregressive method (MS-AR). I've been trying to replicate this method in R, but to no success. There has been some question asking about it lately which can be found here
[Error when using msmFit in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884548/error-when-using-msmfit-in-r)

Basically I'm having the same problem. When I tried to do the MS-AR the error came out. I'm not sure what the exact calculation for the msmFit, but from some examples online they use this to get the fit for MS-AR. So my question is, is it actually possible to do MS-AR(p) in R? Is there any other software besides R or Eviews 8 (since I don't have this at the moment) that can actually do this?

Thank you. Really appreciate your insight.

link msmFit: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/msm/msm.pdf

Answer (score 0):

There is a package for MATLAB called `MS_Regress`, it should do the job:
https://sites.google.com/site/marceloperlin/matlab-code/ms_regress---a-package-for-markov-regime-switching-models-in-matlab

I was trying to fit the MS-AR model in R, but I get the same error message. Could you provide us with a link to the examples you found about getting the fit in R?